# Jenkins LDAP authentication for specific group members

Tags: jenkins, ldap

I need to setup authentication for our Jenkins via LDAP (AD). I was able to setup the authentication on a wide scale but I have to narrow it down to a certain members of a group and my LDAP filtering fails here.

This is the full DN that I want to target:

CN=jenkinsgroup,OU=App1,OU=Applications,OU=CompanyGroup,OU=Company,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com

In the **jenkinsgroup** group I have the users stored as member attributes, only they should get access.

Jenkins LDAP plugin offers these fields:

[Jenkis configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDuMy.png)

I'm not sure whether I should use a filter in on the User or the Group field, or which objectClass or category should I use for member attribute - I tried user and member as well.

Error message I get:

**User lookup: user "username" does not exist.
Does the Manager Dn have permissions to perform user lookup?
Are the user search base and user search filter settings correct?
LDAP Group lookup: could not verify.
Please try with a user that is a member of at least one LDAP group.**

Without the filtering, I can authenticate with a user from the group and it also confirms me its membership.

So I'm confused about how the write the proper query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please copy the config as text/code instead of linking an image so that your post is more readable. The issue is that there is no username variable to substitute in the user search filter, replace that filter with: `(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=jenkinsgroup,OU=App1,OU=Applications,OU=CompanyGroup,OU=Company,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com))`. Also, since this single filter checks for the username and its membership.

Answer (score 0):

As EricLavault commented:

**(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=jenkinsgroup,OU=App1,OU=Applications,OU=CompanyGroup,OU=Company,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com))**

I used this as the user search filter and worked.